# Case insensitive searches using XPATH in R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I've got an XML containing a set of tags with an ID attribute whose value is composed of numbers and lowercase characters.

Using this sample suffices to select desired tags:

#### Sample Code:

```
doc <- XML::xmlTreeParse(file, useInternalNodes = TRUE)
myid <- "123_myID_567" # from <test> attributes
xpath <- paste("//node[@id='", myid,"']/subnode", sep = "")
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(XML::xpathApply(doc, xpath), XML::xmlAttrs)), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

However, in the same XML, uses these same IDs in other tags as well but, **sometimes all lowercase, other times in uppercase**.

#### First attempt:

Trying to use the `lower-case` workaround does not seem to work in XML R package:

```
xpath <- paste("//node[lower-case(@id)='", myid,"']/subnode", sep = "")
```

As I get the following error:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function lower-case not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
XPath error : Invalid expression
XPath error : Stack usage error
Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, xpath) : 
 error evaluating xpath expression //node[lower-case(@id)='123_myID_567']/subnode
Called from: xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, xpath)
```

#### Second attempt:

Tried the other workaround with `translate` neither seems to work:

```
xpath <- paste("//node[translate(@id,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='", myid,"']/subnode", sep = "")
```

Though this time XPATH does not complains but returns nothing.

#### Third attempt:

Trying to use the `matches` workaround does not seem to work in XML R package:

```
xpath <- paste("//node[matches(@id,'", myid,"','i')]/subnode", sep = "")
```

As I get the same error as first attempt:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function matches not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
XPath error : Invalid expression
```

#### Sample XML file

```
<xml>
    <tests>
        <test id="123_myid_567" key="something" status="skipped">
            <Paragraph>some text</Paragraph>
        </test>
        <test id="111_myid_888" key="something" status="skipped">
            <Paragraph>some text</Paragraph>
        </test>
        <test id="222_myid_777" key="something" status="skipped">
            <Paragraph>some text</Paragraph>
        </test>
    </tests>
    <nodes>
        <node id="123_myID_567" title="Sample title" value1="8" value2="4" value3="3.5">
            <subnode> text1 </subnode>
            <subnode2> text_1 </subnode2>
        </node>
        <node id="111_myid_888" title="Sample title2" value1="3" value2="4" value3="7.4">
            <subnode> text2 </subnode>
            <subnode2> text_2 </subnode2>
        </node>
        <node id="222_myid_777" title="Sample title3" value1="2" value2="5" value3="2.5">
            <subnode> text3 </subnode>
            <subnode2> text_3 </subnode2>
        </node>
        <node id="333_myID_567" title="Sample title4" value1="6" value2="7" value3="5.5">
            <subnode> text4 </subnode>
            <subnode2> text_4 </subnode2>
        </node>
    </nodes>
</xml>
```

Comment: some valid, parse-able, example data would prbly get you faster responses.

Comment: Questions should be have complete minimal reproducible code (so inputs need to be included and cut down to the minimum needed to show the problem) .  See [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The reason you are seeing "xmlXPathCompOpEval: function lower-case not found" error message is that XML R package only has support for [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), and does not extend to [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/), while the function lower-case() is found in XPath 2.0

2) You are not getting return in your second quest with translate() function most likely because of the typical problem with default namespaces (not matching default namespaces in data and query). Add prefixes to elements in XPath query and bind these to the default namespace. Problem and solution are explained in the [XML R FAQ](http://www.omegahat.net/RSXML/FAQ.html)

3) Same as 1: matches() function is added in XPath 2.0

Comment: The solution is the second attempt with addAttributeNamespaces set as TRUE:  `XML::xmlTreeParse(file, useInternalNodes = TRUE, addAttributeNamespaces = TRUE)`

Comment: Check [this](https://github.com/omegahat/XML/blob/958c9806999db9dbc7287f6a4456a740714046ee/src/xpath.c#L235): It seems that something is going on with XPATH 2.0 functions, maybe in future versions of XML package.